# JSON Deserealizing issue

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I tried with posted answers from other engineers on stack and other repositories. But not get success.

```
[{
"cdr": "1461920017104140-1000",
"main_cdr": {
    "AcctId": "a",
    "accountcode": "b"
},
"sub_cdr_1": {
    "AcctId": "1",
    "accountcode": "xx"
},
"sub_cdr_2": {
    "AcctId": "2",
    "accountcode": "xxx"
}
}]
```

This is the json I have from client and which is valid, My issue is while deserealizing the same in c# I can't find the way how to handle dynamic number of 
"sub_cdr".

Using below code I tried to deserealize it.

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CDRRootObject>>(json);
public class MainCdr
{
    public string AcctId { get; set; }
    public string accountcode { get; set; }
}

public class CDRRootObject
{
    public string cdr { get; set; }
    public MainCdr main_cdr { get; set; }
    public List<MainCdr> sub_cdrs { get; set; }
}
```

In above json it is upto "sub_cdr_2" but it is upto n. My code get me success upto main_cdr and not after that.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to deserialize too.

Comment: post your object class and how you are deserializing it

Comment: This string doesn't show any nested properties, it's an array that contains a dictionary with keys like `cdr'`, `main_cdr`, `sub_cdr` etc but different contents. The first one is a string, the rest dictionaries themselves. This means you can't create a class to easily deserialize this, you'll have to deal with each element. Or you could deserialize to a `dynamic` variable and try to access properties without help from the compiler

Comment: Just because it's valid json *syntactically* it does not mean it is a valid json *semantically*.

Comment: @PepitoSh indeed sub_cdr_ is screaming array...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the dynamic object as a deserialization result?

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(your_json_string);
```

This will work no matter how many sub_cdr_xxx you have in your json.

Or you can use JArray as following:

```
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(your_json_string);

        var item = result.Children().First();
        var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
        foreach (var itemProperty in itemProperties.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("sub_cdr")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itemProperty.Name);

            MainCdr data = itemProperty.Value.ToObject<MainCdr>();
            Console.WriteLine(data.AcctId);
            Console.WriteLine(data.accountcode);
        }
```

Comment: using dynamic is resource intensive.

Comment: @IteratioN7T not really, the DLR is *very* well optimized. In this case it's either that or handling individual JSON elements which is *more* resource intensive. `dynamic` is unsafe though in the sense that you can't detect misspellings and schema changes until runtime

Comment: i think static will do the job instead of [dynamic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256566/when-to-not-use-dynamic-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This one help you

```
var jsonString = "[{\"cdr\": \"1461920017104140-1000\",\"main_cdr\":{\"AcctId\": \"a\",\"accountcode\": \"b\"},\"sub_cdr_1\": {\"AcctId\": \"1\",\"accountcode\": \"xx\"},\"sub_cdr_2\": {\"AcctId\": \"2\",\"accountcode\": \"xxx\"}}]";
                var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);
                JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(value.First.ToString());
                jobj.Remove("cdr");
                var js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>(jobj.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there`s no way of defining with an arbitrary number of properties with some index number in the property's name.

Preferred solution would be to get your client to change the "sub_cdr_xxx" properties into an array.

If this is not possible, all you can assume (from a type perspective) is that you get an array of objects. So if you use Json.Net, you could deserialize it as an `IEnumerable<JObject>`, then process the `JObject`s to get the desired output:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JObject>>(json)
    .Select(jobj =>
    {
        var cdr = jobj.TryGetValue("cdr", out var token) ? token.ToObject<string>() : null;
        var mainCdr = jobj.TryGetValue("main_cdr", out token) ? token.ToObject<Cdr>() : null;
        var subCdrs = new List<Cdr>();
        for (var i = 1; jobj.TryGetValue("sub_cdr_" + i, out token); i++)
            subCdrs.Add(token.ToObject<Cdr>());

        return new
        {
            Cdr = cdr, // string
            MainCdr = mainCdr, // Cdr
            SubCdrs = subCdrs // List<Cdr>
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

, where `Cdr` is defined as

```
class Cdr
{
    [JsonProperty("AcctId")]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountcode")]
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }
}
```

Personally, I prefer this over `dynamic`.